# How many columns and row can i read from an Excel file in python with pywin32?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I use Pywin32 library.
The following piece of code read up to 6 rows and 19 columns. If i try to read much more the IDLE ppython gui (32bit) seems to be going in a loop. the program neither exit nor itgives me an error.
It is a correct behaviour?

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from tkinter import *
#from tkinter import ttk
#import tkinter


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title('AAAA')
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root,  width=0, height=0)  


        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root,  width=1000, height=550)  #grandezza finestra
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)


        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                                  tags="self.frame")


        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                                  tags="self.frame")


        self.titoli_HFT = ["1", "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","9"]


        for i in range (0,len(self.titoli_HFT)):

            self.lblnome=tk.Label(self.frame, text= self.titoli_HFT[i], font=("Helvetica", 8))
            self.lblnome.grid(row=2, column=i+1, padx=5, pady=15) #place(x=85+j, y=50)



        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)



        self.lettura()




    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))




    def lettura(self):
        xl= Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        xl.Visible = True
        #x2= Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        #x2.Visible = True

        self.checkb_intvar = list()   #contiene una lista di 1 o 0 associati alle checkbox nella lista quadratini
        self.quadratiniH = list()
        self.quadratiniB = list()
        #self.quadratiniB = l = [None] * (13 * len(self.titoli_BFT) )
        #self.quadratiniH = l = [None] * (13 * len(self.titoli_HFT) )


        wbH = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\\Marco\\LAVORO\\Smith&Nephew\\appRonca\\fonte\\HFT_SAP_2.csv')
        print("wbH")

        wsH=wbH.WorkSheets(1) # get a reference to the first sheet


        MAX = 6

        #HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER   
        for i in range(0, MAX):
            #CHECKBOX
            self.checkb_intvar.append (IntVar())
            self.quadratiniH.append(tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text="", variable=self.checkb_intvar[i], onvalue=True))
            self.quadratiniH[i].grid(column=0, row=i+3)  #spunta

            for j in range(0,len(self.titoli_HFT)):
                print("for for")



                contvalueX = i + 1  #con zero da errore allora +1
                contvalueY = j + 1  #con zero da errore allora +1

                self.txt1 = tk.Text(self.frame, width='10', height='1')


                if (wsH.Cells(contvalueX, contvalueY ).Value != None):

                    self.txt1.insert('1.0', wsH.Cells(contvalueX, contvalueY ).Value)#ws.Cells(1,i).Value
                    self.txt1.tag_add("start", "1.0", "1.13")
                    if (contvalueY == 1 ):  #### qui si richiama la funziona regole con tutte le regole
                        self.txt1.tag_config("start", background="white", foreground="red")

                    self.txt1.grid(row=i+3, column=j+1, padx=5, pady=15)  
                    print("if")

                else:  
                    print("else")
                    self.txt1.insert('1.0', "")
                    self.txt1.grid(row=i+3, column=j+1, padx=5, pady=15) 
                    if (contvalueY == 1 ):  #### qui si richiama la funziona regole con tutte le regole
                        self.txt1.tag_config("start", background="white", foreground="red")


        wbH.Close()
        xl.Quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Possibly, using Win32com. It's horrible and poorly documented. I would recommend [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) for reading older (non `.xlsx`) formats. Or more simply still, I notice the file you have hard-coded above is a `.csv` file. In which case look at the standard [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library.

Comment: @SiHa: Why wouldn't you use `xlrd` for reading .xlsx files?

Comment: @JohnY I was under the impression that xlrd was only for the older format. I've just checked, and stand corrected, thanks. The point, really, though was **don't use win32com**, and that point stands...

Comment: There is  an exe file for xlrd for python 3.4?

Comment: i tried to install the targz file in windows with setup.py install but import module  command does not work i tried to install from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.7.1 the exe file but the import module command generate a syntax error: ile "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1187
    print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"

Comment: I installed also  xlrd 0.6 file exe, then i removed and now all it works! Mysterious programming!  But first error:'module' object has no attribute 'open_workbook'